# Any way to configure Sandbox to not show a dialog when the OS inside shuts down?

Tags: shutdown, windows-sandbox

I'd like to use Windows Sandbox to automate some things and that works well, but after my script shuts down the PC in Sandbox the process remains showing a dialog like

```
---------------------------
Windows Sandbox
---------------------------
The connection to the sandbox was lost.

Error 0x80072746. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.


Would you like to submit feedback about this issue?
---------------------------
Yes   No   
---------------------------
```

The only way out I found is polling for the existence of a file my script creates, then killing both the WindowsSandbox and WindowsSandboxClient processes.

Is there instead a way to tell Sandbox to just quit when the OS shuts down so I can wait for process exit?

Comment: Sandbox is just a temporary OS and closes the OS when you shut it down. So I think it works as you show (I use Sandbox occasionally) .  What are you trying to automate?  That is, have you selected the appropriate too?

Comment: @John the automation is testing some software, should run unattended, but that doesn't really matter. Point is: after shutting down the OS inside Sandbox (also just via Start->Shut down) it shows a dialog hence requires user interaction before windowssandbox.exe stops. Which makes it harder to detect when my automated test is done.

Comment: I don't think you can change that. Enter your issue in the Microsoft Feedback Hub.  Make sure you have logged into the Feedback Hub with your Microsoft Account.

Comment: Facing exactly the same issue and resorting to the same solution. @stijn, would love to know if you found a solution.

Comment: @zsimpson no I'm still forcibly killing the processes. If I ever find something else I'll post it as an answer here for sure